# How to calculate average by category in pyspark streaming?

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I have csv data coming as DStreams from traffic counters. Sample is as follows

```
`Location,Vehicle,Speed,`
`tracker1,car,57,`
`tracker1,car,90,`
`tracker1,mbike,81,`
`tracker1,mbike,65,`
`tracker2,car,69,`
`tracker2,car,34,`
`tracker2,mbike,29,`
`tracker2,mbike,76,`
```

I want to calculate average speed (for each location) by vehicle category.

I want to achieve this by transformations. Below is the result i am looking for.

```
Location |  Car | MBike
Tracker 1| 73.5 |  73
Tracker 2| 51.5 |  52.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactaly what you want, but if it's avarage speed by vehicle, by location, than you can use a Window function:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('tracker1','car','57')
    ,('tracker1','car','90')
    ,('tracker1','mbike','81')
    ,('tracker1','mbike','65')
    ,('tracker2','car','69')
    ,('tracker2','car','34')
    ,('tracker2','mbike','29')
    ,('tracker2','mbike','76')
    ],
    ['Location','Vehicle','Speed']
)

from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("Location","Vehicle")

df_pivot = df\
            .withColumn('avg_speed', F.avg(F.col('Speed')).over(w))\
            .groupby('Location','Vehicle', 'avg_speed')\
            .pivot("Vehicle")\
            .agg(F.first('avg_speed'))\
            .drop('Vehicle', 'avg_speed')

expr = {x: "sum" for x in df_pivot.columns if x is not df_pivot.columns[0]}

print(expr)

df_almost_final = df_pivot\
                    .groupBy("Location")\
                    .agg(expr)\
                    .orderBy('Location')

df_final = df_almost_final.select([F.col(c).alias(c.replace('sum(','').replace(')','')) for c in df_almost_final.columns])


df_final.show()



# +--------+-----+----+
# |Location|mbike| car|
# +--------+-----+----+
# |tracker1| 73.0|73.5|
# |tracker2| 52.5|51.5|
# +--------+-----+----+
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I have edited the question a bit to make it more understandable. I want to do transformation operations to convert the data into something like above.

Comment: Than you can pivot, group by and aggregate. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the average by category in PySpark Streaming using the agg() and mean() functions. To do this, you need to first group the data by the category column and then use the agg() function to calculate the mean of all the values in each group. Finally, you can use the mean() function to get the average of each category.

```
df.groupBy("category").agg(mean("value")).show()
```